# Match URL Paths A+ or B+ but not AX+

Tags: regex

I am not good in Regex and need to get an answer on the following problem.

I am trying to match/not match URL Paths
I need to match
/appA  or
/appB

But do NOT Match
/appA/download

This is used within an Apache proxy to identify urls for which to set authentication rules.

```
(^\/(appA|appB))
```

works almost but includes /appA from /appA/Download

I cannot use `(^\/(appA|appB)$)` as that would eliminate all other URLS starting with /appA or /appB.

What I am looking for is a regex which matches the /appA or /appB in

```
/appA
/appA/something
/appB
/appB/something
```

Does not match /appA when /download follows.

```
/appA/download
/appA/downloadsomething
```

Comment: Add an end of string anchor : `(^\/(appA|appB)$)`

Comment: `\/app[AB](?:$|(?!\/download)\/.*)` https://regex101.com/r/gD3Fgk/1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
^\/(app[AB])(?!\/download).*
```

It uses a [negative lookahead](https://www.regextester.com/94366) to check against `download`.

You can see it demo'd [at https://regexr.com/4mqah](https://regexr.com/4mqah).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is a negative look ahead. In regex: `(?!<pattern>)`

Your regex should be able to match the full string using this method (using `^` and `$`) like so:

```
(^\/(appA|appB))(?!\/download).*$
```

The Negative look ahead: `(?!\/download)` will exclude matches where `"/download"` follows right after `/appA` or `/appB`

Note: The `.*` is going to match the rest of the string (ex: `/something` in `/appA/something`) but is optional so `/appA` still is a valid match.

Here is a RegexR to show the examples: [RegexR -  (^/(appA|appB))(?!/download).*$](https://regexr.com/4mqaq)

Comment: Ahh.  THANK YOU that works.  Unfortunately I cannot mark your answer up but it works.